# String to byte array and then to MD5 in Java

Tags: java, hex, md5

in the last 5 hours im trying to do something that should be very simple and did it in like 10 minutes in C#, but no luck with Java.
I got a 32 UpperCase and Numeric String (A-Z0-9), I need to convert this String to Dec, and then md5 it.
My problem is that I dont have unsgined bytes so I cant md5 my array :\

Here is what I need to do in python:

```
salt = words[1].decode("hex")
passwordHash = generatePasswordHash(salt, pw)
generatePasswordHash(salt, password):
    m = md5.new()
    m.update(salt)
    m.update(password)
    return m.digest()
```

and here it is in C# :

```
public static string GeneratePasswordHash(byte[] a_bSalt, string strData) {
    MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

    byte[] a_bCombined = new byte[a_bSalt.Length + strData.Length];
    a_bSalt.CopyTo(a_bCombined, 0);
    Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strData).CopyTo(a_bCombined, a_bSalt.Length);

    byte[] a_bHash = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(a_bCombined);

    StringBuilder sbStringifyHash = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a_bHash.Length; i++) {
        sbStringifyHash.Append(a_bHash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }

    return sbStringifyHash.ToString();
}

protected byte[] HashToByteArray(string strHexString) {
    byte[] a_bReturn = new byte[strHexString.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < a_bReturn.Length; i++) {
        a_bReturn[i] = Convert.ToByte(strHexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }

    return a_bReturn;
}
```

I will be very happy to get a help with this :)

Comment: Java or Python? You are making it kind of confusing.

Comment: I think Python is his source language. He is trying to convert to Java/C# but cannot in Java.

Comment: I am trying to convert the above Phyton and C# codes into Java, which is what im learning now [Java]

Comment: What's a '32 UpperCase and Numeric String (A-Z0-9)'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To parse a hex string into a byte : `(byte) Integer.parseInt(s, 16)`.

To transform your password string into a byte array, using the default encoding (which I suggest not to do : always specify a specific encoding) : `password.getBytes()` (or `password.getBytes(encoding)` for a specific encoding).

To hash a byte array : `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(byte[])`.

To transform a byte to a hex String : See [In Java, how do I convert a byte array to a string of hex digits while keeping leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string-of-hex-digits-while-keeping-l)

Comment: Already tried all of the above, didnt work out as unsigned byte of 246 becomes a -10 and it changes my final hash.

Comment: a byte is a byte. Whether it's considred as a negative number or a positive one doesn't change its internal sequence of bits. It shouldn't change your final hash. Why don't you show us your Java code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/q41uYJL4 - as you can see, I figured that out and its working as suppose to :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that something like the following will work:

```
// convert your hex string to bytes
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(salt, 16);
byte[] bytes = bigInt.toByteArray();
// get the MD5 digest library
MessageDigest md5Digest = null;
try {
    md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    // error handling here...
}
// by default big integer outputs a 0 sign byte if the first bit is set
if (bigInt.testBit(0)) {
    md5Digest.update(bytes, 1, bytes.length - 1);
} else {
    md5Digest.update(bytes);
}
// get the digest bytes
byte[] digestBytes = md5Digest.digest();
```

Here's more ideas for converting a hex string to a `byte[]` array:

- [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Comment: Similar solution for SHA-1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332740/sha1-hash-on-hex-string

Comment: Take a look at here please, http://pastebin.com/gxFT55rt - I wrote what the results should be as I tested it in my working Python app.

Comment: Already figured that out ad you can see above, thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: The problem with my code was that BigInteger adds a leading byte 0 at the front if first character has the high bit set.  I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unsigned numbers in java with applying bit masks. Take a look details [here](http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml).

Comment: Wont help me as I cant md5 chars array.